# No route to host : connect

Tags: java, networking, ip

I am getting my public IP from the website, but sometimes I get this error:

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at Connection.getIp(Connection.java:86)
    at Connection.setIP(Connection.java:31)
    at Connection.connect(Connection.java:67)
```

I guess it's because the system did not get the reply from the web yet, and cannot continue, but im sure that im wrong..

Why does that happen? How can I 'fix' it?

```
public String getIp() throws IOException {
    URL whatismyip = new URL("http://icanhazip.com");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));
    return in.readLine();
}
```

Well this is kind of a VPN management system, so I can reconnect and change the ip of the vpn, but I need to check if the ip has changed and thats how I do it and the error OCCURS from this method:

```
public boolean connect() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String ip = this.setIP();
    if (ip != null) {
        if (ip.equals(this.defaultIp)) {
            System.out.println("equals");
            previousIp = ip;
            HMACommand.connect();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            while (ip.equals(this.defaultIp) || ip == null) {
                if (ip == null) {
                    System.out.println("Is null");
                    return connect();
                }
                ip = this.setIP();
                Thread.sleep(75);
            }

            return true;
        }
        else {
            this.previousIp = ip;
            HMACommand.reconnect();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            while (ip.equals(this.defaultIp) || ip.equals(this.previousIp) || ip == null) {
                if (ip == null) {
                    return connect();
                }
                ip = this.setIP();
                Thread.sleep(75);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        boolean flag = connect();
        return (flag) ? flag : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I guess it's because the system did not get the reply from the web yet": no it isn't. It is because your local IP stack doesn't know where to send the request too. This is a network topology problem, not a computer programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does not look like a problem in the Java code. It is more a lower level networking and routing issue. First of all use system level tools to check the path from your computer to that domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some hours with a "no route to host" - exception. Then I realised I started the application with -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true but the system wasn't configured for IP v6.